# Sci fi cartoon: man with blue robotic arm has trouble using a fork

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I might have dreamed of this; so sorry if this doesn't exist.

I vaguely remember a show from my childhood (animated like an old Batman cartoon) with a character who got his arm injured and has a blue bionic prosthetic. The only scene I remember was him trying to eat with it but having trouble using a fork.

The setting was really futuristic and in a city.

I have tried Googling terms using these keywords with no luck. I thought it was from some sort of Batman show, yet I can't find a character matching this description.

Comment: Welcome to Sci-Fi StackExchange! Be sure to check out the [help section](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help) for more information. Also be sure to check out this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/112267) on how to write a good story identification question!

Comment: Most importantly, when was your childhood? Not to be a creep :) but that'll help narrow the search